# Convert SAR image mat to csv image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a SAR image mat file, the size of image is 512x512x8. I need to convert the mat file to 8 seperate csv format files. The output size of each csv format file should be 512x512.

How could I covert the image format?

Comment: The final result should be 512x512 cvs image

Comment: Raw data is complex-valued, or real-valued?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the 3D array to write out is complex-valued. Here’s a simple function that writes each slice of a 3D complex array to two CSV files, for real and imaginary components, at full precision (i.e., a ton of decimal places).

```
function complex2csv(basename, arr)
%COMPLEX2CSV writes the slices of a 3D complex array to two CSV files each.
%
%  COMPLEX2CSV(BASENAME, ARR) for a string BASENAME and 3D complex array ARR
%  writes each 3D slice of ARR to two ASCII comma-separated value (CSV) files,
%  one for the real and one for the imaginary component.
%
%  The format for file names is: '<BASENAME>-<slice number>-<REAL or IMAG>.csv'.
%
%  If ISREAL(ARR) is true, the second set of files (for imaginary
%  components) will not be created, since it would be filled with zeros.

dlmwrapper = @(filename, data) dlmwrite(filename, ...
                                        data, ...
                                        'precision', '%0.30g');

for i = 1 : size(arr, 3)
  dlmwrapper(sprintf('%s-%d-REAL.csv', basename, i), real(arr(:, :, i)));

  % Only write imaginary if it is there.
  if ~isreal(arr)
    dlmwrapper(sprintf('%s-%d-IMAG.csv', basename, i), imag(arr(:, :, i)));
  end
end
```

You can test this as follows:

```
>> testData = randn(512, 512, 8) + 1j*randn(512, 512, 8);
>> complex2csv('test-image', testData)
```

This spits out sixteen CSV files, *each* 8.3 MB, for a total of 132.8 MB. (The original binary array is just 32 MB—numeric ASCII is brutal for disk space.)

Because all decimal places are printed, you should be able to `dlmread` such text files and get bit-exact copies of the original data (always a plus for any data archival system ).

---

If you have a MAT data file, here’s how I’d convert it. Assume the MAT contains a variable named `IMAGE`.

```
data = load('my-mat-file.mat'); % data is a struct
complex2csv('my-mat-file', data.IMAGE);
```

Comment: Thank you. This answer is very close to the ideal result. But My 3D array is not a complex value. I just want to decomposition the 3rd direction, which is 8

Comment: The function given, `complex2csv` will not create files for the imaginary component if the input is real-only, so you can use it exactly as demonstrated.

Comment: Two probelm. First, there is a error in the running. Undefined function 'iscomplex' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: Second, How could I read the .mat file as the testData as the arguement? Thank you

Comment: @Alice I messed up, `isreal` is standard Matlab, `iscomplex` is not—fixed that. Also, if you already have a MAT file saved and you want to convert a variable inside it, just do `load mymat.mat; complex2csv('mymat', WHATEVER)`. I hate using the naked `load`, though, so the updated answer shows how I’d use `load` returning a struct.